# SeekBarPreference Listener - how is it done?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I have a `SeekBarPreference` in my preference xml file :

```
<SeekBarPreference
        android:defaultValue="50"
        android:key="@string/pref_custom_target_value"
        android:max="99">
</SeekBarPreference>
```

I am trying to add a listener to this preference. I am unable to create an instance of that preference in my `onCreate` method. In addition, I am unable to create a functional inner class to handle this type of preference.

Here is the class I am using to handle user's preferences:

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
```

Any suggestions on how to create a listener?

> EDIT: I ended up creating a `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and added another view that represented the actual `SeekBarPreference`.